URL Format with Params
This is more a theoretical question. Think of an Apache2 Web server where the structure is as following:
public_html
- api/
-- users/
--- index.php
- index.php

In my root index.php, I want to get the users, so I'm calling either one of the following URLs:
/api/users/?q=test
/api/users?q=test
Is there any difference on these two calls, also if the web server would not be an Apache2? What is the accepted way?
